# Iphone SDK: Image arrays?

Tags: iphone, arrays, ios, uiimage, touchesbegan

I'm making a "Tapping-App" where you have to kill zombies by tapping on them. Currently i can't make any progress because i can't use  the methods i need properly.

My App works like that:

I have a timer that spawns an image 3 times per second:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/3 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(Spawn) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:YES];
```

then i have the Spawn command:

```
- (void) Spawn {
    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 109.0f);
    UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
    myImage.opaque = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:myImage];
    [myImage release]
}
```

I also have a "TouchesBegan" command:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];   
}
```

What I want to do, is put all the spawning images into an Array; If one of the images is touched i want it to be removed from the superview.I want to know how an array works and how i can remove objects added to the array from a different function like "TouchesBegan".

Please help me with my problem!

EDIT:

Nevermind... I searched around the internet and found some useful resources witch were almost what i needed. I finally figured out how it works and got my spawner function to work with collision and with "TouchesBegan".

If somebody wants the code, just ask me.

DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NSMUtableArray addObject:] and [NSMutableArray removeObject:]

In your interface, something like:

```
@interface MyClass
{
    NSMutableArray *zombies_;
}
```

In your implementation, after initializing the array, change your spawn method to include the line

```
[self.zombies addObject:myImage];
```

and in your touch handler, after you determine which view was touched, something like

```
[zombies_ removeObject:theView];
[theView removeFromSuperview];
```

Although, after thinking about it, you may be better off just creating UIButton instances instead of UIIMageViews and writing touch handlers to determine which view was touched.

Comment: I already tried it, but for some reason i couldn't get it to work. Can you explain a little more please and make .h and .m examples??          Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tried it again, but now i have 1 error in "TouchesBeagan": The ImageView is undecleared.([self.zombies addObject:myImage];)

Comment: EDIT: I see your edit now. I didn't provide code to determine which view was tapped. So you'd need to do that. Also, it sounds like you are very new to programming. Don't give up, but make sure to try to get an understanding of fundamentals like variables and their declaration.

Comment: Tnx for everything, but what should i do now exactly??

Comment: Um, I'm not going to write your program for you, sorry.

Comment: haha XD i understand! Thank you for everything, you really helped me! But if you could help me declaring the ImageView inside my Touches began, id be even more grateful :)                                        For now il leave the question open, maybe someone will add something to your great answer! Good night!

Comment: If you need help *declaring* the variable, you should read up a basic C tutorial. If you need help determining what to assign to your variable inside your touch handler, you'll have to look at comparing the frames of the views. I still think you're better off using a UIButton or a gesture recognizer.

Comment: Its not about declaring it. The problem is that the "ImageView" is getting spawned over and over PER CODE. Thats why it isnt declared in the "TouchesBegan" function or the InterFace. Any Ideas??

Comment: I glossed over that because I didn't have time to look through the docs, but what you really want is hitTest:withEvent: